# Discord JS - Error: Cannot find module 'node:events' on node v16.14.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently using node v16.14.0 as per the title and getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/discord/bot.js
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/discord/purchase.js
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/webserver.js
- /Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/discord/bot.js',
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/discord/purchase.js',
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/webserver.js',
    '/Users/username/bp/bp-website/backend/index.js'
  ]
}
```

I have looked at other questions, however, they all say upgrade to Node v16.6 which I downgraded to to test but also still didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Output of `node -v`: `v16.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

Run **node -v** in the terminal. If the output is v16.6.0 or higher, you're good to go, because the required version of **discord.js** is v16.6.0 or higher. Click [here](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/#installing-node-js) to read full documentation from discord.js .
Without the latest version of node.js you might get errors like:

1.Unexpected token '?'

2.Cannot find module: 'node:events'

Answer (score -1):

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
```

instead of:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question.